# node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts error. An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, animation, ionic4

**Description : -**

This error occured in Ionic 4 after installing of " 
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`" and imported to app.module.ts `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

**Error Description : -**

```
node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts:133:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

get players(): AnimationPlayer[];
            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts:299:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

get totalTime(): number;
```

**Package.json.**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.6",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.26",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0",
    "ts-node": "8.5.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

**My Question :-** `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` `BrowserAnimationsModule`  will working in Ionic 4/5 .. but In Angular its working properly no issues there i have seen on other hand when adding the this in ionic 4 issues occurred in front if anyone are here to give a hint to overcome this isssues ?